# Размытие всей страницы

Tags: html, css, javascript

Вот [тут](http://callbackhunter.com/), если побыть на сайте 18 секунд, вылетит окошко и весь сайт размоется, вот как сделать такое размытие? (всего сайта)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайте к основному блоку (или же к элементу `body`) добавляется фильтр (css свойство):

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='blur'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation='3'/></filter></svg>#blur");
```

Answer (score 0):

простое окно на jquery. 
Например тут: [пык](http://tradebenefit.ru/vsplyvajushhee-okno-jquery)

достаточно понятно описывается, как его создать. А с таймером по времени - ставим счетчик на Н секунд, после которых выполняем функцию - т.е. вытаскиваем наше окно

Comment: Вы описали как сделать все, кроме того, что я попросил)

Comment: @Fangog там затемнение, размытие сделать сотни способов, как на CSS, так и на JS. 

Например в гитхабе поищите blur.js - при правильном использовании получите желанный эффект

Comment: Знаю библиотеку, размывает изображения
Тут же размыта вся страница, причем как-то заюзано svg (можно глянуть через инспектор)